# Haw to clear all data that my template set to #comments-list from API response

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var showResults = function (title, overview,picture,pictureBack) {
    var $template = $('#comment-template').html();
    $template = $($template);

    $template.find('h4').text(title);
    $template.find('p').text(overview);
    $template.find('#pic').append(picture);
    $template.find('#picBack').append(pictureBack);

    var $commentsList = $("#comments-list");
    $commentsList.append($template);
}
```

I want to reset the template by clicking the button which make research

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could use something like [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) on your `$commentsList` object.

Comment: Yes but I have skills for JAVA, and I don't know haw to do that with JavaScript.

Comment: this is my button for get result from Web API

Comment: $("#search").on("click", function () {       
        var selectedYear = $('#select-year').val();
        loadMovie(selectedYear);

    })

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding the full code such that we can understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: as @AndreasHassing said if you want to reset content in comment list you can do it like this  $("#search").on("click", function () { $("#comments-list").empty(); var selectedYear = $('#select-year').val(); loadMovie(selectedYear); })